# How do I update Visual Studio Code installed using Ubuntu Make?

Tags: ubuntu-make

I have installed VS Code using Ubuntu Make, how do I update it to the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been extensively discussed on [this upstream issue](http://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/74) (and its duplicate) a while ago.

Basically, the philosophy is that the upstream tool has a better idea on how to update itself than us, so we let it (and that's why we don't install it in a zone requesting root access.
For instance, all **JetBrains' based IDEs** like **IntelliJ**, **PyCharm** and **Android Studio** have their own update optimization, downloading only the requested delta (can be few megabytes instead of the whole IDE) and dealing with configuration migration.

So, the vast majority of frameworks and IDEs supported by Ubuntu Make should just be updatable via the auto-update mechanism in the tool itself. For others not supporting those, the easiest way is to **reinstall it** (with the same command you use to install it first). Ubuntu Make will catch the current installation path (even if you modified it), **will warn you that it's not empty** and will download latest available version (with optionally new requirements). If all that is fine, it will **replace the older version with the new one**.

Just a note, be use to grab the [Ubuntu Make ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) if you are not running the development serie in case the upstream web pages parsing changed.